# small little line at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I can't get rid of a small white line in my HTML page at the bottom:

```
.text {
    width: 90%;
}

.divfloatleft {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 35%;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: left;
    background: linear-gradient(#036, #0FF);
    height: 70%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

.divpaginalogin {
    height: 100%;
}

.divfloatright {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 35%;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: right;
    background: linear-gradient(#0FF, #036);
    height: 70%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

.div-container {
    background-image: url(../Images/pellicola.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 88%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.div-child {
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

    .div-child a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .div-child:hover {
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }

a:hover {
    color: #00C;
}

.div-login {
    background: linear-gradient(#003, #00F);
    color: white;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}

.div-footer {
    min-height: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(#00F, #003);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.table-login {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.loginbutton {
    color: white;
    background-color: #0066ff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 65px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is my Razor page:

```
    <div class="divpaginalogin">
        <div class="div-login">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <table class="table-login">
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Username)</td>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Username, new { @class = "text" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password, new { @class = "text" })</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="loginbutton" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)</td>
                        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Username)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="div-container">
            <div class="divfloatleft">
                <div class="div-child" onmouseover="Show(this, 'Contatti.png')" onmouseout="Hide(this)">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Contatti", "Contatti", null, new { @style = "position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" })
                </div>
                <div class="div-child" onmouseover="Show(this, 'Mappa.png')" onmouseout="Hide(this)">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Dove Siamo", "DoveSiamo", null, new { @style = "position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divfloatright">
                <div class="div-child" onmouseover="Show(this, 'Informazioni.png')" onmouseout="Hide(this)">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Informazioni", "Informazioni", null, new { @style = "position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;" })
                </div>
                <div class="div-child" onmouseover="Show(this, 'Chi-siamo.png')" onmouseout="Hide(this)">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Chi Siamo", "ChiSiamo", null, new { @style = "position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="div-footer">
            <p>Videoteca online P.IVA: 00000000000</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

at the bottom appear a line which is about 0.3% height, it seems I can't cover the full HTML page if I add 1% to the footer instead the scrollbar appears, I also use this CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image: Image white line]

I was thinking to set footer height from 5% to 5.3% but I don't know if that's the correcty way since I may be have something wrong in my HTML..

Thanks to all!

Comment: Can you add a plunker link for this page please?

Comment: Sure here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/XWia22bxTfUiCFTYDuJ9?p=preview

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the total height of div-login + div-container + div-footer is supposed to be 100%? Your plunkr doesn't define a height for the div-login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested your page, and with this minor modification in your `.div-footer` class the white line at the bottom seems to be gone. I've tested in several resolutions including mobile.

```
.div-footer {
    min-height: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(#00F, #003);
    border-top: 1px solid black;

    /* changes added to fix footer at bottom */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Here's an edited [Punkler](https://plnkr.co/edit/qtZCIU1iDEY2IsagLPzh?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much! I had just an issuea 'cause I wrong in copy and pasting and I set overflow: auto to the login div instead that on the div that wraps the whole page so when resizing the footer went up in the page, now it's working perfectly sir, thank you again!